# Display new module in site

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-modules

i am new to drupal , 
i created a new module base on this example

```
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--examples--page_example--page_example.module/6/source
```

i just changed the module name and method to my module new name 'jtpc'
and change the jtpc_perm to this

```
function jtpc_perm() {
  return array(
   'access jtpc content' ,
 );
}
```

now how can i view the module in drupal site ?
what is my next step ?

Comment: can someone help me why i dont see my module  menu ?

Comment: i was able to run the example i want a custom page , means , my own php page i creates earlier i tried to include my page but this replace the complete web page

Answer (score 0):

The next step is to implement `hook_menu()`, or/and `hook_form_alter()`. Those are the main ways a module have to be visible to users through pages (or forms) it creates, or pages created from other modules to which attach its own content.

Read [Menu system](http://api.drupal.org/api/group/menu/6), [Forms API Quickstart Guide](http://drupal.org/node/751826), [Forms API Reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6), [Form generation](http://api.drupal.org/api/group/form_api/6), [How to define content (node) types](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--examples--node_example--node_example.module/6), [How to restrict access to nodes](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--examples--node_access_example--node_access_example.module/6), [How to extend existing content types](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--examples--nodeapi_example--nodeapi_example.module/6), and [Default theme implementations](http://api.drupal.org/api/group/themeable/6).

Comment: thanks , i need to view the block ,in order to link to my custom page ?
just want to understand what i am doing

Comment: do i need to see my module under administrator->Site building->menues->navigation ?

Comment: A menu callback shows a page, not a block. To show a block, you need to implement `hook_block()`, which is the other way a module has to show something in a page; a block still needs to be enabled by an administrator. Not all the menu callback can be shown in the navigation menu; the menu callback shown at `/admin/build/modules` (handled by the module system.module) is shown in the navigation menu, but `/devel/php` (handled by devel.module) is not shown in the navigation meanu.

Comment: ok i was able to run the example
i want a custom page , means , my own php page i creates earlier
 i tried to include my page but this replace the complete web page